# built-in monitor recognized when using nvidia driver, but not when using i915?

Tags: display, xrandr, intel-graphics, i915

**TL;DR:
I'm using Pop 20.10. I'm on a Dell G5 5590 w/ RTX 2070mq (working well) and an i7-9750H. I have a 144hz built-in screen. It works when using nvidia proprietary drivers, but does not work (nor even appear in `xrandr`) when the nvidia card is disabled (i.e., using i915/integrated intel gpu instead).**

In windows, I see the screen is 144hz when using nvidia, can be manually set to 64hz if desired. If i disabled the nvidia card, I see the screen running at 64hz automatically.

In Pop, it auto-defaults to using the nvidia drivers for my machine. This works perfectly, but has poor battery life characteristics.

In this mode, `xrandr` shows only a 144hz setting for the built in screen, which matches what I see in windows in the nvidia control panel:

[image: when booted with nvidia]

When I try to switch to 'integrated' and reboot, I can only get video through my external monitors connected via usb-c. DP-0, which xrandr shows as the internal screen when using nvidia, doesn't even show up in xrandr when the nvidia is disabled.

`xrandr` with nvidia disabled:

[image: when booted with integrated]

I've [filed an issue with i915](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/3307), but have seen no response.

I've tried a number of things, [all documented](https://github.com/pop-os/system76-power/issues/221), including `1915.modeset=0` and attempts at `xorg.conf` files, but nothing seems successful--all shots in the dark for me, though, as this isn't an area I am terribly knowledgeable in.

My guess is that the EDID (or perhaps the DisplayPort Configuration Data/DPCD?) is 'incorrect', similar to the issue referenced [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230541&p=2). But I'm pretty over my head trying to debug this on my own, and I'm a bit at a loss of where to go next.

I would also guess, and have in the past, that the iGPU just can't handle the 144hz. But:

1. if that's the case, wouldn't I still see it in xrandr?
2. 144hz of 1080p should be well within the range of what the iGPU is capable of, in theory, but if it won't do that in windows, maybe this is a wrong assumption

In any case, what can I try to get my internal monitor working (perferably at 60~hz, I'd like to maximize battery life) with my intel UHD 630 iGPU?

I would guess that I could add `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with a 60hz modeline, but that hasn't seemed to work for me. I've tried many variations, but I just don't see my monitor. (You can see me giving an example of what conf file I have tried [here](https://github.com/pop-os/system76-power/issues/221#issuecomment-787119673)).

What logs should I look at here? Here's my boot logs for an 'integrated' boot, grepped for `modeset`: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zXsjcpMdMY/ . No mention of DP-0 whatsoever...

However, when I grep through a an nvidia boot, I also see that modeset doesn't ever mention a DP-0 then, either; instead, in an nvidia boot only, I see this line:

```bsh
Apr 07 16:29:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2327]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +2160+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
```

Based on what I'm reading [here](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/100.14.23/README/chapter-19.html#:%7E:text=The%20NVIDIA%2DAuto%2DSelect%20Mode&text=The%20%22nvidia%2Dauto%2Dselect%22%20mode%20is%20intended%20to,detailed%20timings%20from%20the%20EDID.) when I look up `nvidia-auto-select`, it seems the nvidia driver is told to manage DP-0, and then does, successfully. However, since I don't see DP-0 mentioned at all in xrandr when not booting with nvidia, I'm unable to debug that issue further than this without figuring out *where* knowledge of `DP-0` comes from in the system, *how* it gets to be told to use `nvidia-auto-select`, etc., so that I could instead start telling DP-0 to get utilized when the nvidia card/driver are not active.

I think the parent process running is [this code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/blob/master/daemon/gdm-x-session.c), but I'm not able to get much value from that, as I'm just not a C developer and don't know much about how this kind of project is organized.

If some other logs would be helpful, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i spent also a couple of days on this issue on my Dell G5 5590 and conclude on the fact the bios itself do not mention the intel UHD 630 as a video card.
When trying an xorg.conf with modesetting (intel) only, it seems to correctly upload i915 driver, all fine but nothing happened on the screen.
Then i think we tried something not foreseen...with linux and we are damned to use the nvidia card only.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/442487)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but I had a similar issue.

I have an MSI GS66 and I'm duel booting pop and windows. One day I was trying something and switched my graphics on pop to discrete and when I changed it back to integrated I just got a blank screen on boot up.

So I went to Windows to see if I brick my PC somehow but it worked fine and would switch cards fine. I was able to boot into pop with the discrete card but when I changed it to mshybrid in windows just a grey screen.

How I fixed it was go into the BIOS, changed the graphics from discrete to mshybrid then will it was booting hit the spacebar a bunch and I think it brings up systemd. Anyway it gave me three options first was to continue in current kernel the second was to boot into older kernel and third was firmware. I picked the older kernel and it booted just fine all my apps and stuff were loaded and working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i spent also a couple of days on this issue for my DELL G5 5590 and conclude on the fact the bios itself do not mention the intel UHD 630 as a video card.
When trying an xorg.conf with modesetting (intel) only, it seems to correctly upload i915 driver, all fine but nothing happened on the screen.
Then i think we tried something not foreseen...with linux and we are damned to use the nvidia card only.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/442486)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).